# Berlin Sans system font doesnt work in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have **Berlin Sans FB Demi** font as a system font which works fine in Google Chrome/Safari/Opera/IE but doesnt work in firefox. Kindly point out the issues if anyone has faced already.

**CSS**

```
.ipoints, .runs, .Rank, .badges {
   font-family:"Berlin Sans FB Demi";   
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example, such as in JSFiddle?

Comment: I see no problem with Berlin Sans FB Demi in Firefox on Win 7, in a simple test. Please provide minimal but sufficient code that reproduces the problem, and identify the operating system used. Also please check whether some other fonts work; a browsers might be set to ignore *all* font suggestions on pages.